# Website red page highlight with crosshairs tool?

Tags: chrome-browser

I was just busy working on a Magento website with the chrome developer tools open. I'm not sure what I pressed but all of a sudden my mouse turned into a crosshair and everything except the block I was hovering over turned a see through red color. It was similar to when you choose "Select an element in the page to inspect it" in developer tools, except with that option the item you are selecting changes color and this time it was everything other than the item I was selecting. When I clicked on the page an information box opened in the bottom right of my screen with the path of image I was hovering over and some other information underneath. I clicked to close it too fast and now want to know what it was I opened. Does anyone know what this tool is?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Magento. Please ask it on another forum

Comment: My bad, i thought i was on stack overflow. I would still assume though that someone working on magento websites has come across this tool before.